# How to change the default disabled EditText's style?

Tags: android, styles, android-edittext, default

It isn't looking nice when using EditText enabled="false". How can I change it
automatically for all of the controls?

I've added this image for reference. [image]

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the `android:background="...."` attribute to the `EditText`?

Comment: If I change android:background in style.xml it changes all of the EditText, not only disabled. I would like to know if I can change default-disabled-EditText style, not one by one.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the color file define your color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color"/>
</selector>
```

In the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:text="whatever text you want"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/example" />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I need for both states, enabled and disabled.
If i try with your code (adapted) my edittext keeps invisible (because it doesn't get correct params.) and log shows me this error:

<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Comment: How can i do it programatically ..??

Comment: Selectors must be defined in the `drawable` directory (not `color`).

Comment: @giraffe.guru text color selectors must be defined under the `color` folder

Answer (score 66):

Create a custom selector in drawables and set it as

`<EditText android:textColor="@drawable/edit_text_selector" />`

**1)** in 'colors.xml' define the color for enabled and disabled state:

```
<color name="enabled_color">#F7FE2E</color>
<color name="disabled_color">#000000</color>
```

**2)** in 'drawable/edit_text_selector.xml':

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color"/>
    <item android:color="@color/enabled_color"/>
</selector>
```

**3)** in your layout.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/customEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Hello!"
    android:textColor="@drawable/edit_text_selector" />
```

Comment: Awesome approach!. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know its old, but @color/normal_color should probably be @color/enabled_color