# Android EditText. Text visibility in readonly mode

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I set EditText in readonly mode, the Font color and its background become almost unable to read. Pls, see the pic

[image]

## Question: how to keep its appearance the same in ReadOnly mode from code?

UPDATE: Thank you for your help.. I published my solution.. I forgot to mention "FROM CODE"

```
EditText ed = new EditText(this);
ed.setId(myId);
ed.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
ed.setText(myText);

int[][] states = new int[][] { new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled} };
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK };
ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
ed.setTextColor(myList);
ed.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

In the color file define your color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color"/>
</selector>
```

In the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:text="whatever text you want"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/example" />
</EditText>
```

[How to change the default disabled EditText's style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337063/how-to-change-the-default-disabled-edittexts-style)

Answer (score 0):

put into color file

```
<color name="visiblecolor">#F7F7F7</color>
<color name="invisiblecolor">#000000</color>
```

creating a drawable XML file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/invisiblecolor"/>
<item android:color="@color/normal_color"/>
```

and put a ref into edit-text

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/customEditText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:enabled="false"
android:text="Hello!"
android:textColor="@drawable/xyz.xml" />
```